# Call UdpClient.Send() inside System.Timers.Timer event does not work

Tags: c#, sockets, timer, udpclient

in my application I receive an UDP stream and I forward it on two other UDP endpoints.
My problem is that I need to put a delay between the two streams, so I thought to use a Timer.
This is my code (where I show only the relevant methods):

```
public void Start()
{      
  Socket udpSocket = m_udpLocalClient.Client;

  udpSocket.ReceiveBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE;

  // Enable broadcast
  udpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                            SocketOptionName.Broadcast,
                            1);
  // Enable reusing address
  udpSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
                            SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress,
                            true);

  // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
  udpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, m_ListenPort));

  m_udpLocalClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(m_ListenIP));

  udpSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(m_data,
                             0,
                             m_data.Length,
                             SocketFlags.None,
                             ref m_ListenEndPoint,
                             new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), 
                             m_udpLocalClient);
}

public void TimerCallback(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  byte[] Data = new byte[m_BytesReceived];

  m_Timer.Stop();

  m_Mutex.WaitOne();
  m_Buffer.Get(Data);
  m_Mutex.ReleaseMutex();

  //Send Packets lo LocalHost EndPoint
  m_udpLocalClient.Send(Data, Data.Length, m_LocalEndPoint);

}    

void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult iar)
{
  int recv = 0;

  try
  {
    UdpClient udpReceiver = (UdpClient)iar.AsyncState;

    recv = udpReceiver.Client.EndReceiveFrom(iar, ref m_ListenEndPoint);
    if (recv == 0)  return;

    //Forward packets on the FwEndpoint
    m_udpFwClient.Send(m_data, recv, m_FwEndPoint);

    //Send Packets lo LocalHost EndPoint
    //m_udpLocalClient.Send(m_data, recv, m_LocalEndPoint);

    m_Mutex.WaitOne();
    m_Buffer.Put(m_data);
    m_Mutex.ReleaseMutex();

    if (!m_Timer.Enabled) m_Timer.Start();

    udpReceiver.Client.BeginReceiveFrom(m_data, 
                                        0,
                                        m_data.Length, 
                                        SocketFlags.None,
                                        ref m_ListenEndPoint,
                                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData),
                                        udpReceiver);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     //...handle....
  }

}
```

NOTE. The m_Buffer member is a CircularBuffer from [CodePlex](http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/).

The problem here is that the call to

```
m_udpLocalClient.Send(Data, Data.Length, m_LocalEndPoint);
```

into the TimerCallBack seems to not have effect, while if I uncomment the same one into the ReceiveData it works.

I also try to use the async method BeginSend() but with no success. Where I wrong?

Regards,
Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that because you're immediately going back to a Receive state after you have received some data, you're not allowed to send data using that same socket in your timer callback.  At the time the timer is executing, you've already told the socket to wait for more data to come in.

You'll need to use a different socket/UdpClient for sending data in your timer callback.

Comment: Hi @villecoder, you're right, but I change my code to use another UdpClient to send out datagrams and still not works.

Comment: Sorry, you're right!
I simply created a new UdpClient: m_udpLocalSender = new UdpClient();
and I use it into the Timer callback: 
m_udpLocalSender.Send(Data, Data.Length, m_LocalEndPoint);
I wrong?

Comment: Send should give you the number of bytes sent. Is it non-zero? If it is non-zero, then the data has been sent to m_LocalEndPoint. Verify that and also that at that time, there is a listener waiting for data at m_LocalEndPoint.